# Proxy bounties and their philosophical implications in today's modern society

Tags: discussion, bounty

There are some questions like this one:

[How to find out where a macro is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8513/how-to-find-out-where-a-macro-is-defined)

where a bounty is offered to an answer that is not upvoted a lot and not the accepted answer. The bounty is offered for a different reason than awarding the answer to that question.

It could be that future users mistake the bounty as "hey, this answer must be the correct answer, as it has such a high bounty".

What do you think?

Comment: Furthermore, the question is bumped for no particular reason, drawing attention to it although nothing has really changed.

Comment: What are some other examples, and do they all come back to this same user, or one of the other names by which they were previously known?  Because they have sort of an amicable vendetta against the reputation system.

Comment: From the comment on the bounty, it seems that [<fill-in-current-name>](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19356/bugbusters) is awarding 2000 in bounties to Herbert for some other answer, but because there is a limit on any one bounty he's applying it to other (random?) answers of Herbert.

Comment: If a mod comes along: I think we can informally change the meta-tag {bounty} to {bounties} since we prefer plural tags. If you think this should be discussed in a dedicated thread, let me know.

Comment: @AlanMunn The bounty comment will vanish once the bounty is awarded, won't it?

Comment: Next time I will selectively, carefully, smartly, properly choose the posts (either answers or questions)  to which my bounties will be assigned to avoid this side effect.

Comment: @Bugbusters Is the bounty on [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111813/12850) a result of the new selection process?

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Yes.The OP has not executed the green check mark.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't want to sound harsh, but bounty is not a way to give reputation to a user for any different reason than *the answer which is awarded the bounty*. If the problem is that bounty of 500 seems not enough for that particular case (and the offerrer wants to give more reputation to one particular answer), the offerrer can make a feature request to increase the maximal bounty size.

However, in my opinion, bounties awarded after the answer was posted are meant as "thanks" and "I like this answer", and 500 rep points is, in my opinion, sufficient for that in all cases. Remember that rep points are not everything ;)